# Unix -microfocus: Find a word after a specific word

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I would like to know to find word in a file after a specific word and I explain to with an example.

**File.txt**

```
03 WS-COUNTER            PIC X(03).

PROCEDURE DIVISION.

A-MAIN 

MOVE ZEROES TO WS-COUNTER
```

In this example, I would like to know how to find the word `WS-COUNTER` after `PROCEDURE DIVISION`. If I execute in unix a `grep -i "WS-COUNTER" File.txt`.

I find two positive results, but I would like to find only the second one.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Yes, it's cobol microfocus

Answer (score 1):

not easy in a single grep, you can try this

awk

```
awk '/PROCEDURE DIVISION/{F=1} F && /WS-COUNTER/{print;exit}' File.txt
```

sed

```
sed -n '/PROCEDURE DIVISION/,/WS-COUNTER/{ /WS-COUNTER/{p;q;}}' File.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot NeronLeVelu